# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Card

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm practically done with my project and I get this error:

*"The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Card"*

It's on the line that reads:  `deck[i] = newCard[i];` Here's the code:

```
public class Deck
{
    //nextCard is used to keep count of which number card you are on in the deck.
    public int nextCard;
    private static final int DECK_SIZE = 52;

    //deck is used to represent an entire deck of cards.
    Card[] deck;
    //hand is a pair of 7 cards; is generated by dealACard();
    Card[] hand;

    /**
     * Default Constructor        
     *
     * <hr>
     * Date created: Feb 17, 2014 
     *
     * 
     */
    public Deck ( )
    {
        int i;
        nextCard = 0;

        for(i=0;i<DECK_SIZE;i++)
        {
            Card newCard = new Card(i);

            deck[i] = newCard[i];
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the array brackets to use the instance of `Card` that you just created

```
deck[i] = newCard;
                 ^
```

Comment: Dang. Beat me to it. =D

Comment: Oh wow. I'm an idiot. Thanks man. I dunno what I'm thinkin..-.-zZ

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
deck[i] = newCard[i];
```

Means:

```
Put the object at index i from my Array newCard into index i in my Array deck
```

What you actually want is

```
Put this object newCard into index i in my Array deck
```

because `newCard` is not an Array, it is a `Card` object which is the type your Array `deck` holds. Just change your code to:

```
deck[i] = newCard;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this situation man. I'm gunna give it to @Reimeus though, he did answer first. I watched it in real time.

Comment: No prob! Reimeus's answer was nice and succinct!